# TypeORM jsonb array column

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typescript, orm, typeorm

I'm working on a node micro-service, orm and db are respectively `typeorm` and `postgresql`

I'm trying to create `jsonb` array column but I'm probably not doing it the correct way.

**Notes**

1. I would normally have accomplished this by simply adding a simple extra entity and relation. In this case I have been asked to use the `jsonb` type in oder to be able to amend the interface without catering for schema changes.
2. Storing a simple list of indexed ids would be equally good enough for now.
3. I am not sure I should be using the `array: true` column option. I made a few attempts to use a plain `jsonb` object without succeeding ( `"{}"::jsonb` ).

**My aim:**

To store an array of objects with an **indexed** `id` column, and to be able to add and remove ids. In case this is not possible a flat indexed string array would do.

e.g:

`[ {id: 'some-uuid-000'}, {id: 'some-uuid-001'}, ... ]`

or:

`['some-uuid-000', 'some-uuid-001', 'some-uuid-002']`

**Code:**

My column definition :

```
@Column({
        type: 'jsonb',
        array: true,
        default: () => 'ARRAY[]::jsonb[]',
        nullable: false,
    })
    public users: Array<{ id: string }> = [];
```

I manage to fetch the empty array with

```
const group = await repo.findOneOrFail({ id: groupId });
console.log('>>>>>', group.users);
```

which outputs:

```
>>>>> []
```

when trying to add an item to the array and persist as below

```
return repo.update(groupId, { users: [...group.users, { id: userId }] });
```

I get the following output:

```
2019-12-21 14:40:44.088 UTC [556] ERROR:  malformed array literal: "[{"id":"cc135b8a-b6ed-4cd7-99fc-396228e74509"}]"
2019-12-21 14:40:44.088 UTC [556] DETAIL:  "[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.
2019-12-21 14:40:44.088 UTC [556] STATEMENT:  UPDATE "group" SET "users" = $2, "created_at" = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE "id" IN ($1)
(node:5050) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: QueryFailedError: malformed array literal: "[{"id":"cc135b8a-b6ed-4cd7-99fc-396228e74509"}]"
```

The output error tells me that the configuration must be wrong as postgres seems to be provided with a plain objects array while expecting a different format/notation. I haven't found much details about this sort of scenarios in the docs.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Eventually I found the following solution: the culprit was the `array` column option which needs to be explicitly set to false as in the example below:

```
@Column({
        type: 'jsonb',
        array: false,
        default: () => "'[]'",
        nullable: false,
    })
    public users!: Array<{ id: string }>;
```

When not set typeorm automatically inferred the postgres column type to be `jsonb[]` (rather than plain `jsonb`) which doesn't allow performing `jsonb_set` operations.

Comment: One will still get error,
error: malformed array literal: "[]"

Answer (score -4):

```
@Column('simple-array', { nullable: true })
  toId!: string[];
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: [simple-array](https://typeorm.io/entities#simple-array-column-type) is not applicable here because the OP is trying to store JSON in Postgres and not just regular strings. `simple-array` has the caveat that the values cannot contain commas(,).