# QueryFailedError: malformed array literal: "[]" in typeORM

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I'm trying to add a new row to a table in postgres using TypeORM, but receive the issue related to array literals. The problem occurs with a `subscriptions` field

Entity format:

```
export class User {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  userId: string;

  @Column("varchar")
  email: string;

  @Column("text", { array: true })
  userCookieIds: string[];

  @Column("varchar", { array: true })
  userLocalIds: string[]

  @Column("jsonb", { array: true })
  subscriptions: object[]  
}
```

The code of typeORM insert:

```
        user = new User()
        user.userId = uuidv4()
        user.email = ''
        user.userCookieIds = [userCookieId]
        user.subscriptions = []
        user.userLocalIds = []        
        await this.usersRepository.save(user)
```

I checked all similar questions on StackOverflow, but it didn't help :-(

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: guessing you fixed this already but can you share the error text with us? I think you can drop [] from the data types when you specify {array:true}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned here: [TypeORM jsonb array column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59437390/typeorm-jsonb-array-column) and here: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/4674 I deleted an `array: true` from `@Column` specification. After I dropped the postgres table and recreated it from scratch, everything statred to work as expexted.